# Remove colon from part of text via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, regex, get, indexof

I had a similar question posted previously but this is a little bit different.  I am looking to remove the colon from the below price code utilizing jQuery.

```
 <font class="pricecolor colors_productprice">
       <div class="dealtext"></div>
       :  $58.05
 </font>
```

So far I believe it could be somewhat accomplished like this, I just need another set of eyes to correct it:

```
$('.pricecolor:contains(" : ")').remove(colon??);
```

It still doesn't seem right, perhaps I need a var set with a `get()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('*').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(":", ""));
});
```

Comment: Works for OP's example, but not very robust. That simply zaps the first colon it sees - http://jsfiddle.net/veVyY/. Ouch.

Comment: Good point Shawn, fortunately I will only ever need to zap one colon.  So for future reference one may have to modify for multiple removals.

Comment: @Shawn is right; what you might consider doing is to put the price inside a separate container: `<span class="price">$58.05</span>` and then using `$('span.price')`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question as I needed it and I ultimately used this function to do something similar...

```
$('.pricecolor:contains(" : ")').html(function(index,oldhtml) {
    return oldhtml.replace(' : ','');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findAndReplace(elements, textToFind, textToPlace) {
            $.each(elements.contents(), function () {
                // This is added to make sure the nodes you request are text nodes
                if (this.nodeType == 3)
                    this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(textToFind, textToPlace);
            });

        }

        findAndReplace($('div.dealtext'), ':');
```

Comment: this seems like a very ***heavy*** way to do this.. regular expressions would be a much better solution. Remember `$.each` runs very slow. Also you are making a tremendous number of DOM calls which will also bogg down the browser.

Comment: I voted up your comment because it's valid but my method works to replace all colons in the entire DOM. My solution is obviously not preferable in this situation because the OP only want to remove one specific colon but there are certain scenarios where my code might be necessary.

Comment: I only commented for your benefit. I see a lot of people relying too heavily on JQuery to do the simple things that can be done with traditional (framework-less) javascript. Not to say your code is not useful, i'm sure it is. Just pointing out some areas where performance may take a hit. watch this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU&feature=channel_video_title

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like below.

```
  $(".pricecolor colors_productprice").html($(".pricecolor colors_productprice").html()replace(/:/g, ""))
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = $(".pricecolor:contains(':')");
e.text(e.text().replace(/\s*:\s*/, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$(".pricecolor:contains(' : ')").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(" : ", ""));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
$('.pricecolor:contains(" : ")').text(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace(/:/g, "");
});
```

I think you need to pass a function instead of a string to $.text() like this to avoid mangling other content that was found using the '.pricecolor:contains(" : ")' selector.